# Is there is a way to get the address of a register?

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-address, cpu-registers

Is there is a way to get the address of a register? For example, the address of the eax register (not it's content).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "address of a register"?

Comment: [Are CPU general purpose registers usually memory mapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52308185) (spoiler alert: no)

Answer (score 8):

Registers are the internal processor storage. **They do not have memory addresses, because they do not reside in memory**. You identify them by their names: EAX, for example.

That said, memory-mapped registers do exist, but in any modern processor they belong to other devices, never the CPU. They are assigned "fake" memory addresses for convenience. See [memory-mapped I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O).

Comment: I would add to that that they also are not mapped to the RAM, either. Many hardware devices have registers that have "addresses" since there's mapping going on. The only thing here is that x86 does not expose these registers by making them mappable.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi : Does same is true for the 64 bits version of the architecture ?

Comment: they do reside in memory, this memory is just mapped differently than ram, and ram is not mapped to these registers(since this would make them slower than both). each register has its own identifier which for the purpose of the cpu represents its address in register memory. It is possible to map register memory to main memory, no differently than it is possible to expose registers over a network and in response to packets have the server modify the registers in a specific context; it's just rarely warranted to do this.

Comment: @Dmitry when we say "memory" without any additional clarification, we refer to the main RAM space. Of course, anywhere values are stored is _technically_ computer memory, but that's rarely the intended meaning. Memory-mapped registers exist, but they belong to other devices, and **not the main CPU registers in any modern processor** (though historically there have been CPUs that did this). As for mapping registers over the network, this is not a hardware feature at all. You need a complex operating system in place to achieve anything remotely like that. I extended the answer to clarify

Answer (score 7):

There has been architectures where low addresses were used to designate CPU registers, like the Univac 1100 series of computers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC_1100/2200_series

Current x86 hardware doesn't work that way, so you cannot get the address of the EAX register - it just doesn't have one.

Comment: Some microcontrollers still do have memory-mapped registers, for example AVR (8-bit RISC with 32 GP registers): http://www.avr-tutorials.com/general/avr-memory-map.

Answer (score 4):

Registers are physical electrical components inside the CPU's circuitry. They are not in RAM and so have no address. To access it's contents you use the `mov` instruction.

Comment: `Registers are physical electrical components inside the CPU's circuitry` The same is true for ʀᴀᴍ in the case of ꜱᴏᴄ.