# Are CPU general purpose registers usually memory mapped?

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers, memory-mapping

I am confused about Memory Map and Memory mapped I/O.
Do general purpose registers, for example in ARM Architecture r0, r1, etc., are generally memory mapped?

Comment: Memory mapped registers are common on the ARM platform as they related to devices.  On the x86, there is a notion of programmable I/O.  It originally had two types of buses (and still does?).  Compare [Von Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture) vs [Harvard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture).  Conceptually, you can have a third bus for I/O versus program memory (be it instruction or data).  You need CPU instructions that will use the alternate buses.  ARM also has 'co-processor' instructions with `mcr` and `mrc` which some peripherals/devices use.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, those registers are inside the actual CPU (or CPU core for multi-core CPUs). You can not access them through loads or stores to any memory address.

A memory-mapped register is something which you access through an address or a pointer (in languages that have pointers). I/O devices often have memory-mapped registers, where you write to or read from a specific address to set or get information or data. In other words, they are accessed just like any other memory (e.g. RAM).

---

As mentioned in comments, there *do* exist CPUs with memory-mapped CPU registers. They were almost all designed in the 1970's and are part of history now. The chances you would encounter a mainstream CPU (not microcontroller) with memory-mapped registers these days are slim to none.

Some microcontroller architectures do still use memory-mapped registers, including old designs like [8051](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8051), and even some more recent designs like [PIC microcontrolers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_microcontrollers) and [AVR](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/56304) (an 8-bit RISC with thirty-two 8-bit registers).  AVR MCUs come with at least 128 bytes of internal SRAM, the low 32 of which is also the register file.

Specifically for ARM, the ARM architecture does *not* have memory-mapped CPU registers.  Peripherals, including those on the same SoC as the CPU's, are a different matter though: I/O registers are not at all the same thing because they're not also accessible via register-numbers as operands for instructions other than load or store.  (And aren't even inside the core running your instructions.)

Comment: I agree with this answer.  In my experience of dozens of CPU architectures, memory mapped registers are very uncommon.  The [PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11) has them and so does the [TI-9900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments_TMS9900) but no others come to mind.  Note that those two architectures are from the 1970s.

Comment: Also the 8-bit PIC devices, which have so little RAM that typically all of the RAM is seen as registers from a programmer's perspective.  But this lack of a clear distinction between registers and RAM is very rare.

Comment: there have been and are processors where the general purpose processors are memory mapped yes.  The arm is not one of those.  So we can see the OP's confusion.

Comment: the 8051 might as well, dont think it was AVR, so probably it was 8051 but would have to check...and yes I would expect this kind of feature to be something from that era at least for general purpose processors...

Comment: @old_timer True, the only register not being memory-mapped on 8051 was the PC. And it had a lot of other quirks common of that early micro-processor era.

Comment: @wallyk: AVR (8-bit RISC microcontroller) has memory-mapped GPRs.  [How do I directly access a memory mapped register of AVR with C](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/56304) has a map of memory address space (including the 32 GPRs in the low 32 bytes), and the I/O address space that overlaps that.

Comment: Mitch Alsup's My 66000 maps the registers to memory addresses. While there is no hardware implementation, the ISA design is modern. (I think the ISA is still pre-1.0.)

Comment: Actually, for My 66000 the thread context is memory mapped, but this does allow software to write into registers from another thread. I am not certain if the synchronization aspect has been fully defined yet (particularly for a thread writing its own registers), but as I understand it a running thread can have its register state updated from an external source.