# Can I get RIP address in C?

Tags: c, cpu-registers

Basically I am trying to get RSP, RBP and RIP addresses into pointers.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[500];
    int *rsp;
    int *rbp;
    int *rip;
    strcpy(buf, "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    ptr = buf;
    printf("[buf:%p:%s]\n[rsp:%p:%s]\n", &buf, buf, rsp, rsp);

    return 0;
}
```

The above pointer works just fine while getting the RSP address. But I don't know how to get the RBP and RIP addresses.

Can you tell me how can I point *rbp to `RBP` address and *rip to `RIP` address?

Comment: Maybe you should be doing whatever you're trying to do in assembly, instead.

Comment: My assembly knowledge is quite rusty so I may be wrong but I don't believe that x86 registers have addresses.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, Am kinda noob in assembly, but still learning, if not possible with C, we probably can add the assembly part into my c right? if so can you tell me how?

Comment: @amiTheregroot depends on the compiler. For example for gcc take a look [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Comment: what is your architecture? 64bit x86 processor?

Comment: @GuillaumeD intel x86

Comment: C itself is agnostic to the nuances and implementation details of particular architectures. You will have to use an intrinsic or inline assembly to achieve this.

Comment: Are you talking about the addresses *stored in* RIP, RBP, etc., or the *address of* those registers? The latter doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Caleb the address and what is stored in there, e.g 0x7fffffffe980: 0x41414141

Comment: @GuillaumeD my bad it's 64bit

Answer (score 1):

- Current x86 hardware doesn't work that way, so you cannot get the address of the any register - [it just doesn't have one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301292/is-there-is-a-way-to-get-the-address-of-a-register).
- What does it mean?
  It means you can get the value of each register but you cannot get the address of the registers - they have none.
- For instance, if you do at the beginning of a function the following, you'll get the address your RIP is pointing to.

```
void foo(param a, param b)
{
   int dummy;
   int* rip = &dummy;
}
```

But note that you this won't be accessible outside this function.

Comment: okay that make sense, but I just dids `#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[500];
    int *ptr;
    strcpy(buf, "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    ptr = buf;
    printf("[buf:%p:%s]\n[ptr:%p:%s]\n", &buf, buf, ptr, ptr);
    int dummy = 0;
    int* rip = &dummy;
    printf("[rip:%p:%d]\n", rip, dummy);
    return 0;
}
` breaking from line 10 until the program exit, printing `x/x $rip`, no where do I see the gdb output to be the same as my code `printf(rip)`.

Comment: do it "at the beginning" of any function

Comment: dummy won't point to the RIP, it will point to the local variable on the stack