# NASM Allocate an Array Filled with Values from Registers

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm, cpu-registers

I am writing a simple NASM assembly program which will get the value of one of 16 64-bit registers (`rax` thru `r15`) when given a `long` number `i` (`0` thru `15`) corresponding to that register. My approach is to allocate an array containing the values of the 16 registers and then read the array at index `i`. My code is as follows:

```
SECTION .data
    ; array containing all our registers
    regs    dq rax, rbx, rcx, rdx, rsi, rdi, rbp, rsp, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, r13, r14, r15

SECTION .text

global getReg

getReg:
    ; rdi is the first argument we got, and the registers are 8 bytes each,
    ;  so the desired index is our argument multiplied by 8
    imul   rax, rdi, 8
    ; move the quadword at index rax of regs array into register rax (for returning)
    mov    rax, [regs + rax]
    ret
```

However, when I attempt to assemble the above with `nasm -f elf64 getReg.s -o getReg.o`, I get `expression is not simple or relocatable` 16 times (once for each register) on line 3. I'm new to assembly and am pretty much at a loss (struggling to understand what the error even means and what it is symptomatic of). Would love some help and potentially some related tips on other errors in my file or general NASM best practices. Thanks!

Comment: What is the `regs...` line meant to do exactly?

Comment: Operands for `dq` have to be link-time constants, like integers or symbol addresses.  Register contents only exist at run-time.  There's no way to set up a region of memory that mirrors register values on x86 or most other ISAs.  A few ISAs like AVR have their registers memory-mapped at a specific address, so even then you wouldn't be able to set up a custom mapping.  Remember that assembly language is a very low level language; each line can only emit bytes into the current section or not.  Anything that happens at run-time has to be triggered by machine code the CPU executes.

Comment: Also note that you got the register numbering mixed up.  The first 4 register numbers in x86 machine code are RAX, RCX, RDX, RBX.  ([Why are first four x86 General Purpose Registers named in such unintuitive order?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5121))

Comment: Related: [Are CPU general purpose registers usually memory mapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52308185) / [Is there is a way to get the address of a register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5301292) (you can't in most ISAs)

Comment: If you want to index the current values of registers at run-time, you need to store them all to an array (with 16 `mov` or `push` instructions), or you need to compare-and-branch or do an indirect jump to blocks of instructions like `mov rax, r13` / `jmp done`, with only `i=0` special-cased to not need any instructions to get the value into RAX, i.e. its jump target can just be the "done" address.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError The `regs` line is meant to allocate an array of 16 items with the value stored in `rax` at index 0, `rbx` at index 1, etc. However, Peter's comments have convinced that that is not the correct approach.

Comment: It is also *possible* to use SMC (Self-Modifying Code) to encode one of the 16 registers into a single instruction which will have the desired register as a source. However, it is easier and better practice to create a dispatch table (like a C `switch`) and jump to a short bit of code that hardcodes the corresponding register. Like @PeterCordes suggested.